# perform query if document contains a word has low score

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I created a Lucene index and want to find all documents that **contain** a certain word or phrase.
When i do that, i recognized that the score gets lower the longer the text is that contains that word.

How can I create a query that only checks for the existence of a word in my documents / fields?

That's how I created the index

```
public static Directory CreateIndex(IEnumerable<WorkItemDto> workItems)
    {
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
        Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        foreach (WorkItemDto workItemDto in workItems)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("Title", workItemDto.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
            //doc.Add(new NumericField("ID", Field.Store.YES, true).SetIntValue(workItemDto.Id));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }

        writer.Dispose();

        return index;
    }
```

And this is how i created the query:

```
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
        Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Title", analyzer).Parse("Some");

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDir);
        TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(query, 10);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.ScoreDocs;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, is it the normalization based on field size that annoys you or simply that you don't care about the score and you would like to speedup your query by not computing the score? For the former see how to tune the similarity parameters (tuning the b param in BM25), for the latter wrap your query inside a ConstantScoreQuery.

Comment: I'm expecting the query to return the same score for different text lengths of the fields I looking for. Because I just want to know if the word exists in a field.
Yes, it's the normalization based on the field length!

Comment: Sorry I did not notice it was lucene.net (you should probably remove the lucene tag). please ignore what I wrote it's certainly not compatible with lucene.net